# If $a$ and $b$ are elements of an abelian group with $(|a|,|b|)=1$, then $|ab|=|a||b|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

How we can prove in an abelian group if an element *a* has order *k* and an element *b* has order *j* and if *k* and *j* are relatively prime then the element a*b has the order *kj*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(ab)^{kj}=a^{kj}b^{kj}=(a^k)^j(b^j)^k=1^j1^k=1$. So it remains to prove that if $(ab)^n=1$ then $kj|n$.

Assume $(ab)^n=1$, then $a^n=b^{-n}$. Choose $p,q$ such that $pk+qj=1$, which is possible since $k,j$ are relatively prime. Then $1=a^{npk}=b^{-npk}=b^{-n(1-qj)}=b^{-n}b^{nqj}=b^{-n}$, hence $b^n=1$, which implies $j|n$. Similarly, $k|n$, so $kj|n$.

Comment: One can give a slightly different proof that if $(ab)^n=1$ then $k$ divides $n$. For $((ab)^n)^j=1$. But $b^{nj}=1$, so $a^{nj}=1$. Thus $k$ divides $nj$, and because $k$ and $j$ are relatively prime, it follows that $k$ divides $n$.