# $gh = hg, \ \gcd(|g|, |h|) = 1\Rightarrow|gh| = |g||h|\ \ (|a|$ = order of element $a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $g,h \in G$. I need to prove that if $g$ and $h$ commute and their orders are coprime, then $|gh| = |g||h|$, that is, the order of their product is the multiple of their orders.

Since $gh = hg$, then $(gh)^{ lcm(|g|, |h|)} = e$, so, $|gh|$ divides $lcm(|g|, |h|)$. Since $\gcd(|g|, |h|) = 1$, then $lcm(|g|, |h|) = |g||h|$.

So, $|gh|$ divides $|g||h|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1 = (gh)^k\! = g^k h^k\Rightarrow\, g^k\! = h^{-k} =: \color{#c00}f\in \langle g\rangle\cap\langle h\rangle\Rightarrow\,  |f|\ {\Large\vert}\ \overbrace{|g|,|h|}^{\rm coprime}\,\Rightarrow |f|=1\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{f = 1}$

So $\,\ (gh)^k = 1\iff g^k =\color{#c00} 1 = h^k\!\iff |g|,|h|\mid k\iff\! |g|\,|h|\mid k,\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\,|gh| = |g||h|$

Comment: How do you get the last implication? If $|g|, |h| \mid k$ then $|g||h| \mid k$?

Comment: @AlJebr By the [LCM universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242), i.e. $\,a,b\mid k \iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid k.\,$ Here $\,a,b = |g|,|h|\,$ are coprime $\gcd(a,b) = 1\,$ so $\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab\,$  [by here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/920978/242).  Thus for coprime $\,a,b\,$ we have $\,a,b\mid k\iff ab\mid k\ \ \ $

Comment: Compare [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/328161/242)

Answer (score 14):

You can find $|gh|$ divides $|g||h|$ already from $$(gh)^{|g||h|}=g^{|g||h|}h^{|h||g|}=e^{|h|}e^{|g|}=e.$$
On the other hand,
$$ e=(gh)^{|gh||h|}=g^{|gh||h|}h^{|gh||h|}=g^{|gh||h|}$$
implies $|g|$ divides $|gh||h|$. As $\gcd(|g|,|h|)=1$, we conclude $|g|$ divides $|gh|$. Similarly, $|h|$ divides $|gh|$. Again using $\gcd(|g|,|h|)=1$, we finally have $|g||h|$ divides $|gh|$.